# Adding New Bullet Item (Using Awesome-CV Template)

Tags: awesome-cv

I am using the Awesome-CV template (https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) and am attempting to add a new bullet point under the "Honors and Awards" section under each of those items.

[image]

So, the bullet point would be under the "2014 Finalist" point as an example. I'm clearly a beginner to Latex so I am not sure where to add this or how to format it. Thanks in advance.

The code for this section is:

```
\cvsection{Honors \& Awards}
    \cvsubsection{International}
    \begin{cvhonors}
      \cvhonor
        {Finalist}
        {DEFCON 22nd CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
        {2014}
      \cvhonor
        {Finalist}
        {DEFCON 21st CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
        {2013}
      \cvhonor
        {Finalist}
        {DEFCON 19th CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
        {2011}
      \cvhonor
        {6th Place}
        {SECUINSIDE Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Seoul, S.Korea}
        {2012}
    \end{cvhonors}
```

I am hoping to have it similar to the bullet point in the following image:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please help us to help you by providing a small part of your code containing the referred section and starting with `\documentclass` command plus ending with `\end{document}`. This is called a MWE (minimal working example) and it is not always needed but it is almost always advisable and gives you much more possibilities to get a fast answer to your request

Comment: I have updated the original post, I hope that is sufficient information. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really read the documentation of `awesome-cv` template but I found out that inside `cvhonors` environment you can not use an `itemize` environment.

This (for me) means that `cvhonors` environment is already a fixed `enumerate` or `itemize` environment with a way that you can not really use a "nested" `itemize` inside of it.

My fix is to break the environment (See my added `\end{cvhonors}` and `\begin{cvhonors}`) and add a minipage between them with your `itemize` environment.

The usage of the minipage is because we have to reduce the distance of the
bullet points that are still obeying at template's special distances.

My MWE is here:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\begin{document}
\cvsection{Honors \& Awards}
    \cvsubsection{International}
    \begin{cvhonors}
      \cvhonor
        {Finalist}
        {DEFCON 22nd CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
        {2014}
        \end{cvhonors}\vspace{-5pt}

            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item test 1
            \item test 2
            \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}\vspace{-5pt}

            \begin{cvhonors}
      \cvhonor
        {Finalist}
        {DEFCON 21st CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
        {2013}
      \cvhonor
        {Finalist}
        {DEFCON 19th CTF Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Las Vegas, U.S.A}
        {2011}
      \cvhonor
        {6th Place}
        {SECUINSIDE Hacking Competition World Final}
        {Seoul, S.Korea}
        {2012}
    \end{cvhonors}

\end{document}
```

PS: This can be said a MWE but it needs many of the fonts from your link

Output:

[image]